# Labelの表示・非表示

Tags: swift3

swift3で、配列の要素の有無でラベルの表示･非表示を切替えたいのですが、うまくいきません。
下記のコードだと、（q9Labelの配列要素は有りで、q10Labelは無し）テキスト表示はq9Label有り、q10Label無しで表示され合っているのですが、ラベル自体（backgroundColor有り）が非表示になりません。
訂正箇所、その他の方法などがありましたら教えて頂きたいのですが、宜しくお願い致します。

```
let q9Label = UILabel()
let q10Label = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    q9Label.text = dArray[21]
    q9Label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 470, width: 335, height: 30)
    q9Label.textColor = UIColor.black
    q9Label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    if q9Label.text != nil {
        view.addSubview(q9Label)
    }


    q10Label.text = dArray[23]
    q10Label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 500, width: 335, height: 30)
    q10Label.textColor = UIColor.black
    q10Label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    if q10Label.text != nil {
        view.addSubview(q10Label)
    }
}
```

Comment: dArrayの中身がわかりませんが、dArray[23]がnilではなく、空文字列("")になっていませんか?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。dArrayの中はcsvファイルから取得した要素なので空文字列などは作成してないのですが、元のcsvファイル[23]以降は値はなく次の行に改行(index)になってます。

Comment: q10Labelが文字は表示されないけれどラベルは表示されていると言うことは、非nilな何かが入っているということなので、if文の所にブレークポイントを置いて、q10Label.textの値を参照してみるか、if文の前に`print q10Label.text`というデバッグ行を挿入して内容を確認してみるのが一番だと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。print q10Label.textをデバッグエリアに出力させるとOptional("")となり、空文字列が入ってました。csvファイルの方の、要素の少ない行にカンマ区切りが自動的に生成（一番多い行のタブ数に合わせて）されていたようでした。なので、if q10Label.text != "", q10Label.text != nil {
            view.addSubview(q10Label)
        }　と記述して、ラベルを消せるようになりました。

Comment: 本当にありがとうございました。もし他によりよい方法・コード記述などありましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

はじめまして。

まず、q9/q10LabelはaddSubviewしないで、Storyboardやxibで画面に最初から配置しておいて`weak IBOutlet`で、q9/q10Labelとバインドしておけばいいのではないかとおもいます。
そうすれば、Label.frameなどをコードに書かずにコードがすっきりすると思います。

上のようにアプリの作り方を変えることで、q9/q10Labelが指すラベル部品はviewのサブビューとして実体があるので、常に表示されることになります。

次いで、各ラベルの表示、非表示は

```
if q9Label.text == nil {
    q9Label.hidden = true
}

if q10Label.text == nil {
    q9Label.hidden = true
}
```

とすると親`view`の中に実体があるけれど非表示になると思います。